# PaperClip ruby on rails inconsistent image sizing on upload

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using PaperClip in ruby on rails to handle image uploading for a model. It is working well apart from an inconsistent handling of image sizes.

See this example:

[image]

See how the picture on the far right is larger than the pictures in the middle and on the left?

I need to identify why this is happening.

This is my development paperclip configuration:

```
#Paperclip storage locally and specify location of imagemagick
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTS = {
     :styles => { :thumb => '100x100#', :medium => '450x300>', :large => '600x400>'},
     :convert_options => { :all => '-quality 100' },
     :processor       => [ :cropper ]
   }
  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

And I am showing these images using the following bit of code:

```
<div class="container">
<% count = 0 %>
<% results.each do |event| %>
<% if count == 3 %>
  <div class="row"></div>
<% end %>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
<ul class="deals">
<li class="impression">
<%= link_to(event) do %>
<%= image_tag event.logo.url(:medium) %>
<div>
<h2><%= event.className %></h2>
<div><%= event.company_name %></div>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<span>£<%= event.ppt %></span> 
£<%= event.ppc %></td>
<td>4 bought</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<% end %>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<% count = count +1 %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

When I investigate the actual img sizes after the HTML is rendered they are as follows:

Tennis pic : 334 x 209 (Original image size is 1024 x 640)

Computer Training pic : 334 x 209 (Original image size is 1600 x 1000)

Zumba pic : 334 x 223 (Original image size is 1280 x 854)

For some reason the Zumba picture is 14 pixels longer than the others?! Why is this happening - why is Paperclip not resizing consistently in this configuration? Or is it to do with the css for the page?!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to ignore the aspect ratio in imagemagick as per :

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#noaspect

I therefore changed the configuration options to be :

```
#Paperclip storage locally and specify location of imagemagick
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTS = {
     :styles => { :thumb => '100x100!#', :medium => '450x300!>', :large => '600x400!>'},
     :convert_options => { :all => '-quality 100' },
     :processor       => [ :cropper ]
   }
  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Note the ! in the '100x100!#' which has been added - this is what tells imagemagick to ignore the aspect ratio - which was the reason I was having inconsistently sized images before I added the !.

Wahoo. ! .